# Corrupt response from Google Oauth server in the Base64/Json encoded claims section of the id_token when requesting the OpenID

Tags: oauth, google-api, openid

How do I deal with this corrupt response when using Oauth as the login mechanism for my website?  I'm implementing Oauth login that will replace the Open ID login that I had previously been using.

1. I redirect the user to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth` to request their permission.  I'm using the scope `email profile openid` and the openid.realm of `http://subdomain.mysite.example.com`
2. The user accepts the permissions and comes back with a `code` parameter.
3. I submit this code parameter to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` along with my app credentials.
4. Google sends back a JSON repsonse that includes an `access_token` and an `id_token`.
5. I have to parse the `id_token` to determine the identify of the user.  The token is three base64 encoded sections delimited by periods (`.`).  I split it on periods and look at the middle one which has the "claims" information I'm looking for.   The other sections are cryptographic signatures which I ignore since I'm communicating directly with Google over HTTPS.
6. The claims is supposed to be a JSON object when I decode it, but occasionally it is corrupt.  When it is is corrupt, the corruption is always around the open id section.

Here is an example of the `access_token` (the data here is for my own account):

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjM1MzExZDJiMWI2OTQ0NTVkYmY2ZmE4YTUyYTNmNzZkYTUwMDUwM2IifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJhY2NvdW50cy5nb29nbGUuY29tIiwic3ViIjoiMTAwNDkwNzU0NjA0MjY0MTgxNzg0IiwiYXpwIjoiMTAwMzUzNDIwNDkwOC1nM3Z1bDAzb2phbGRkZjN0NmxlMjdvMG9xZWhzazNmNy5hcHBzLmdvb2dsZXVzZXJjb250ZW50LmNvbSIsImVtYWlsIjoic3Rvc3Rlcm1AZ21haWwuY29tIiwiYXRfaGFzaCI6Im1kalkxdTlEQ2VXcEVwWC15N0h3enciLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6dHJ1ZSwiYXVkIjoiMTAwMzUzNDIwNDkwOC1nM3Z1bDAzb2phbGRkZjN0NmxlMjdvMG9xZWhzazNmNy5hcHBzLmdvb2dsZXVzZXJjb250ZW50LmNvbSIsIm9wZW5pZF9pZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lmdvb2dsZS5jb20vYWNjb3VudHMvbzgvaWQ_aWQ9QUl0T2F3bDR4NlZXVE1fbHVWSGhwb1VqTlE1VE56c3BzcjFqTF8wIiwiaWF0IjoxNDA1NDI2MDQ0LCJleHAiOjE0MDU0Mjk5NDR9.UWEZZOhJfg5CGEHd9FNnYg__tiAysmMABk_Q0wSGaq6jbXPwe91J4JXwSgpwVBa09St7zjLRL-ajswMe-qooBe_ItzaEhXPgfc6pKWBSIWeqaj-PM2lyXECWQTAwxsm8xtBXCtjJUfyyjp3ciA95g7Rz9JHPTGDJRMywkFhb-fc
```

Then here is the extracted middle "claims" section:

```
eyJpc3MiOiJhY2NvdW50cy5nb29nbGUuY29tIiwic3ViIjoiMTAwNDkwNzU0NjA0MjY0MTgxNzg0IiwiYXpwIjoiMTAwMzUzNDIwNDkwOC1nM3Z1bDAzb2phbGRkZjN0NmxlMjdvMG9xZWhzazNmNy5hcHBzLmdvb2dsZXVzZXJjb250ZW50LmNvbSIsImVtYWlsIjoic3Rvc3Rlcm1AZ21haWwuY29tIiwiYXRfaGFzaCI6Im1kalkxdTlEQ2VXcEVwWC15N0h3enciLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6dHJ1ZSwiYXVkIjoiMTAwMzUzNDIwNDkwOC1nM3Z1bDAzb2phbGRkZjN0NmxlMjdvMG9xZWhzazNmNy5hcHBzLmdvb2dsZXVzZXJjb250ZW50LmNvbSIsIm9wZW5pZF9pZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lmdvb2dsZS5jb20vYWNjb3VudHMvbzgvaWQ_aWQ9QUl0T2F3bDR4NlZXVE1fbHVWSGhwb1VqTlE1VE56c3BzcjFqTF8wIiwiaWF0IjoxNDA1NDI2MDQ0LCJleHAiOjE0MDU0Mjk5NDR9
```

Which Base64 decodes to a corrupt JSON object.  Here is a snippet from the corrupt section:

```
"openid_id":"https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/idYPR]Ø]Û
```

I originally thought it was a character encoding issue.  I'm using UTF-8 when decoding the base64 to a string.   I've tried using other encodings and all appear corrupt.   I'm thinking it is not character encoding related also because the corruption is happening in a URL which should all be ASCII.

This bug only appears to happen with some accounts, but when it happens, it happens consistently for that account.  Even logging out of Google completely does not solve the problem.

I first saw this problem when I deleted my test app in the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com) and created a new app with new credentials.    My Google account was fine with the old app, but has the problem under the new app.

Am I doing something wrong, or does Google have a bug?

Answer (score 0):

You might not be decoding the token properly.

I went to https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/jwtdecoder and pasted the token you provided:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjM1MzExZDJiMWI2OTQ0NTVkYmY2ZmE4YTUyYTNmNzZkYTUwMDUwM2IifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJhY2NvdW50cy5nb29nbGUuY29tIiwic3ViIjoiMTAwNDkwNzU0NjA0MjY0MTgxNzg0IiwiYXpwIjoiMTAwMzUzNDIwNDkwOC1nM3Z1bDAzb2phbGRkZjN0NmxlMjdvMG9xZWhzazNmNy5hcHBzLmdvb2dsZXVzZXJjb250ZW50LmNvbSIsImVtYWlsIjoic3Rvc3Rlcm1AZ21haWwuY29tIiwiYXRfaGFzaCI6Im1kalkxdTlEQ2VXcEVwWC15N0h3enciLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6dHJ1ZSwiYXVkIjoiMTAwMzUzNDIwNDkwOC1nM3Z1bDAzb2phbGRkZjN0NmxlMjdvMG9xZWhzazNmNy5hcHBzLmdvb2dsZXVzZXJjb250ZW50LmNvbSIsIm9wZW5pZF9pZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lmdvb2dsZS5jb20vYWNjb3VudHMvbzgvaWQ_aWQ9QUl0T2F3bDR4NlZXVE1fbHVWSGhwb1VqTlE1VE56c3BzcjFqTF8wIiwiaWF0IjoxNDA1NDI2MDQ0LCJleHAiOjE0MDU0Mjk5NDR9.UWEZZOhJfg5CGEHd9FNnYg__tiAysmMABk_Q0wSGaq6jbXPwe91J4JXwSgpwVBa09St7zjLRL-ajswMe-qooBe_ItzaEhXPgfc6pKWBSIWeqaj-PM2lyXECWQTAwxsm8xtBXCtjJUfyyjp3ciA95g7Rz9JHPTGDJRMywkFhb-fc
```

was decoded to:

Header:

```
{ "alg": "RS256", "kid": "35311d2b1b694455dbf6fa8a52a3f76da500503b" }
```

Claims:

```
{
  "exp": 1405429944,
  "sub": "100490754604264181784",
  "iss": "accounts.google.com",
  "email_verified": true,
  "at_hash": "mdjY1u9DCeWpEpX-y7Hwzw",
  "openid_id": "https:\/\/www.google.com\/accounts\/o8\/id?id=AItOawl4x6VWTM_luVHhpoUjNQ5TNzspsr1jL_0",
  "azp": "1003534204908-g3vul03ojalddf3t6le27o0oqehsk3f7.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "iat": 1405426044,
  "email": "REMOVED_TO_AVOID_SPAM",
  "aud": "1003534204908-g3vul03ojalddf3t6le27o0oqehsk3f7.apps.googleusercontent.com"
}
```

So your OpenID looks to be `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawl4x6VWTM_luVHhpoUjNQ5TNzspsr1jL_0"`.

If you use Java you can get the same result using Apache commons Base64 class:

```
String str = "eyJpc3MiOiJhY2NvdW50cy5nb29nbGUuY29tIiwic3ViIjoiMTAwNDkwNzU0NjA0MjY0MTgxNzg0IiwiYXpwIjoiMTAwMzUzNDIwNDkwOC1nM3Z1bDAzb2phbGRkZjN0NmxlMjdvMG9xZWhzazNmNy5hcHBzLmdvb2dsZXVzZXJjb250ZW50LmNvbSIsImVtYWlsIjoic3Rvc3Rlcm1AZ21haWwuY29tIiwiYXRfaGFzaCI6Im1kalkxdTlEQ2VXcEVwWC15N0h3enciLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6dHJ1ZSwiYXVkIjoiMTAwMzUzNDIwNDkwOC1nM3Z1bDAzb2phbGRkZjN0NmxlMjdvMG9xZWhzazNmNy5hcHBzLmdvb2dsZXVzZXJjb250ZW50LmNvbSIsIm9wZW5pZF9pZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lmdvb2dsZS5jb20vYWNjb3VudHMvbzgvaWQ_aWQ9QUl0T2F3bDR4NlZXVE1fbHVWSGhwb1VqTlE1VE56c3BzcjFqTF8wIiwiaWF0IjoxNDA1NDI2MDQ0LCJleHAiOjE0MDU0Mjk5NDR9";
System.out.println(new String(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(str.getBytes())));
```

Comment: Java 6/7 new class javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter will not work with these Google Base64 strings. For some reason I have to stick to commons codec.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, I had to switch from com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.util.Base64 to org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;